# multiple logins using sharedpreference in android

Tags: android

I am working on shared preference in android.
I have made single user login page and my login details are saved properly.
login page code is

```
`public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int register = Menu.FIRST;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        String pref = "mypref";

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Button loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        editText3.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("name",""));
        editText4.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("password", ""));

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lg = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class);
                startActivity(lg);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.add(0, register, 0, "Register");
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case register:

                Intent lg = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(lg);

                return true;
            case R.id.register:


                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}`
```

Now I want to save multiple users through shared preference on login page. Can anyone suggest some code?

Answer (score 0):

When storing(during signup) in SharedPreference use username entered by user as key and password entered by him as value. Then while logging in take username & password and check if such an entry exists in preference.

Hope you got what I meant. Let me know if you need clarification

EDIT :

When you are storing username and password do the following

```
 sharedPref.put(username, pwd); //username & pwd are user entered
                               //values during sign up
```

When logging in to check if the credentials are correct do the following

```
if(pwd.equals(sharedPref.get(username)) return true;
else return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a `JSON` structure as this one:

```
{
"users":[
{
"name":"name1"
,"password":"pass1"
}
{
"name":"name2"
,"password":"pass2"
}
]
}
```

And then you can fill data in this structure:

```
JSONArray mArrayUser = new JSONArray();
JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
user.put("name", "name1");
user.put("passwords", "pass1");

mArrayUser.put(user);

user = new JSONObject();
user.put("name", "name2");
user.put("passwords", "pass2");

mArrayUser.put(user);


JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
jObject.put("users",myArray);
```

Now you can convert in an string this JSONObject and save it in sharedpreferences:

```
String sharedPrefData = jObject.toString();

editor.putString("YOUR_DB", sharedPrefData);
```

When you need your data you can get it from sharedpreferences and convert it in a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sharedPreferences.getString("YOUR_DB",""));
```

And get every row through the JSONArray:

```
JSONArray jArray= jObj.getJSONArray("users");


    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

        String name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        String password = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("password");
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH THE DATA

    }
```